# Is there a way to programmatically choose a certificate for a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser request and if so how can this be done?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

The problem I'm having is with IE and other browsers by default looking for client certificates in the `Certificates - Current User`. I want to grab a specific one from the `Certificates (Local Computer)` store (I've got the code written for this already) and use it as the one the user chooses or choose one for them if possible. Choosing one for them would be the optimal solution.

Also I'm not 100% locked into using `WebBrowser`, but I just need a way to embed a browser into a windows form and have that web browser be able authenticate via client certificates. I have code written that does this via `HttpWebResponse`, but I wasn't able to use it inside my `WebBrowser`.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem. However your last paragraph turns your question in to a bit of a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you don't really care about `HttpWebResponse` but you explicitly say in your question *"... and have that web browser be able to use an `HttpWebResponse` ..."* (I have deleted my old now non relevant comments, you should do the same)